# Vertica Dynamic Max Timestamp from all Tables in a Schema

Tags: sql, vertica

System is HP VERTICA 7.1

I am trying to create a SQL query which will dynamically find all particular tables in a specific schema that have a Timestamp column named DWH_CREATE_TIMESTAMP from system tables. (I have completed this part successfully)

Then, pass this list of tables to an outer query or some kind of looping statement which will select the MAX(DWH_CREATE_TIMESTAMP) and TABLE_NAME from all the tables in the list (200+) and union all the results together into one list.

The expected output is a 2 column table with all said tables with that TS field and the max of each value. Tables are constantly being created and dropped, so the point is to make everything totally dynamic where no TABLE_NAME values are ever hard-coded.

Any idea of Vertica specific ways to accomplish this without UDF's would be greatly appreciated.

Inner Query (working):

```
select distinct(table_name)
from columns
where column_name = 'DWH_CREATE_TIMESTAMP'
and table_name in (select DISTINCT(table_name) from all_tables where schema_name = 'PTG_DWH')
```

Outer Query (attempted - not working):

```
SELECT Max(DWH_CREATE_DATE) from

WITH table_name AS (
                    select distinct(table_name)
                    from columns
                    where column_name = 'DWH_CREATE_DATE' and table_name in (select DISTINCT(table_name) from all_tables where schema_name = 'PTG_DWH'))
SELECT MAX(DWH_CREATE_DATE) 
FROM table_name
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that in one SQL .
You can used the below  method for node    max   timestamp columns  values

```
select projections.anchor_table_name,vs_ros.colname,max(max_value)  from vs_ros,vs_ros_min_max_values,storage_containers,projections where vs_ros.colname ilike 'timestamp'
              and  vs_ros.salstorageid=storage_containers.sal_storage_id
              and vs_ros_min_max_values.rosid=vs_ros.rosid 
              and storage_containers.projection_name=projections.projection_name
              group by projections.anchor_table_name,vs_ros.colname
```